How to close a BottomSheet after a delay in Flutter?
I have a Flutter app with a button that opens a BottomSheet, and within that BottomSheet, there's another button that opens a dialog. My goal is to close the BottomSheet after a delay (1 second) after the dialog is opened, but currently, the dialog is popping up instantly without waiting for the BottomSheet to close.
Here’s the relevant code:
Adding await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)); before calling Navigator.pop(context) to delay closing the BottomSheet, but the dialog pops up immediately instead
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sheet and Dialog Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Open Sheet and Dialog')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _openBottomSheet(context);
          },
          child: const Text('Open Sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void _openBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  // Keep a reference to the BottomSheet
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (context) {
      return BottomSheetContent();
    },
  );
}

class BottomSheetContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheetContent({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        top: 16,
        left: 16,
        right: 16,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          const Text('This is the Bottom Sheet'),
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: ()async {
              _openDialog(context); // Open the Dialog
            await  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
             Navigator.pop(context); // Close the Bottom Sheet
            },
            child: const Text('Open Dialog'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _openDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('This is a Dialog'),
          content: const Text('The previously opened bottom sheet is closed.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context); // Close the dialog
              },
              child: const Text('Close'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}




To keep a dialog open after closing a bottom sheet in Flutter, use an Overlay for the dialog instead of the standard showDialog. This decouples the dialog from the bottom sheet's navigation stack, ensuring the dialog remains visible even after the bottom sheet is dismissed.
Step-by-Step Solution

Open the Bottom Sheet:  Use showModalBottomSheet as usual to display the bottom sheet.
Display the Dialog Using Overlay: Instead of showDialog, create and insert an OverlayEntry to show the dialog. This ensures the dialog is independent of the bottom sheet's context.
Close the Bottom Sheet After a Delay: Use Future.delayed to close the bottom sheet after a specified duration, leaving the overlay-based dialog open.

Sample Code
Here's the revised code with the necessary corrections:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sheet and Overlay Dialog Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void _openBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled:
          true, // Allows the bottom sheet to take full height if needed
      builder: (BuildContext bottomSheetContext) {
        return const BottomSheetContent();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Open Sheet and Dialog')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _openBottomSheet(context);
          },
          child: const Text('Open Bottom Sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomSheetContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheetContent({super.key});

  // Method to show a custom Overlay Dialog
  void _showOverlayDialog(BuildContext context) {
    final overlayState = Overlay.of(context);

    late OverlayEntry overlayEntry; // Declare overlayEntry first

    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent, // Make background transparent
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, // Dialog background color
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                    offset: const Offset(0, 5),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'This is a Dialog',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const Text('The Bottom Sheet will close in 1 second.'),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      overlayEntry.remove(); // Close the dialog
                    },
                    child: const Text('Close'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    // Insert the OverlayEntry into the Overlay
    overlayState.insert(overlayEntry);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        top: 16,
        left: 16,
        right: 16,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // Wrap content vertically
        children: [
          const Text('This is the Bottom Sheet'),
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Show the Overlay Dialog
              _showOverlayDialog(context);

              // Close the Bottom Sheet after 1 second
              Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                if (context.mounted) {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the Bottom Sheet
                }
              });
            },
            child: const Text('Open Dialog'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Explanation

Overlay-Based Dialog:

OverlayEntry: Creates a separate layer for the dialog, ensuring it isn't tied to the bottom sheet's Navigator context.
Positioned & Material: Positions the dialog and provides material styling.
Close Button: Removes the OverlayEntry when pressed.


Closing Bottom Sheet:

After inserting the OverlayEntry, a Future.delayed schedules the bottom sheet to close after 1 second using Navigator.of(context).pop().
Since the dialog is part of the Overlay, it remains visible even after the bottom sheet is dismissed.



Benefits

Decoupled Navigation: The dialog isn't affected by the bottom sheet's lifecycle.
Persistent Dialog: Ensures the dialog stays open independently until explicitly closed.

References

Flutter Overlay Documentation

